# jlist listModel arrayOutOfBounds at 20 items

Tags: java, swing, jlist, listmodel

I have a `DefautListModel` which reads file names from a directory. Whenever I have more than 19 files I get:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 20 out of bounds for length 20
```

I tried `ensureCapacity()` for the `listModel`.
I tried `setVisibleRowCount()` for the `Jlist`

Any suggestions?

```
    // get the file list
    String[] newList = getFileList();
    // create a list model
    listModel = new DefaultListModel<>();
    listModel.ensureCapacity( 1000 );
    for (String s : newList) {
      listModel.addElement(s);
    }

    // add the model to the jlist
    recipeList = new JList(listModel);
    recipeList.setName( "recipes" );
    recipeList.setSelectionMode(javax.swing.ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
    recipeList.setLayoutOrientation(javax.swing.JList.VERTICAL);
    recipeList.setVisibleRowCount( recipeList.getModel().getSize() );
    JScrollPane toScroll = new JScrollPane( recipeList,
            JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS,
            JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER );
```

Comment: Where does the exception occur?

Comment: Chances are, that somewhere in **your** code, you compute an invalid index, and use that. So, look carefully at the stack trace, and identify how/where **your** code shows up in that stack trace. I would be really really surprised if you found a bug in the java listmodel or jlist implementation. It is much more likely that some code of yours is "off by one", thus leading to this exception.

Comment: I know what causes a arrayIndexOutOfBounds. The exception occurs when reading the file names in after 19 files have been added to the directory

Comment: DefaultListModel is initiated without any size. I thought it would read the files in the directory and that would set the size.

Comment: You were right. I set the size for fileList to 20. I could only read in 20 files.

Comment: @rasweeny What caused the error